# Replacing a particular word in a scanned in string and concatenating using substring() in Java

Tags: java, substring, java.util.scanner, string-concatenation

I'm brand new to all of this so I am trying to write a simple bit of code that allows the user to type in text (saved as a string) and then have the code search for the position of a word, replace it and join the string back together. I.e.:

'I like foo for lunch'

foo is found at position 7

The new input is: I like Foo for lunch

Here is what I have thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FooExample
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    /** Create a scanner to read the input from the keyboard */

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a line of text with foo: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The string read is: " + input);


    /** Use indexOf() to position of 'foo' */

    int position = input.indexOf("foo");
    System.out.println("Found \'foo\' at pos: " + position);

            /** Replace 'foo' with 'Foo' and print the string */

    input = input.substring(0, position) + "Foo";
    System.out.println("The new sentence is: " + input);
```

The problem is occurring at the end -- where I am stumped on how to tack the rest of the sentence on to the concatenation:

```
input = input.substring(0, position) + "Foo";
```

I can get the word to be replaced but I am scratching my head over how to get the rest of the string attached on.

Comment: Maybe you should substring STARTING from the position after "foo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight update to what Achintya posted, to take into account you don't want to include "foo" again:

```
input = input.substring(0, position) + "Foo" + input.substring(position + 3 , input.length());
```

Comment: To clarify, the +3 means that the second substring skips over the original "foo" (which is 3 in length).

Comment: *face palm* I'll remember that for later! The simplest thing caught me off guard! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
input = input.substring(0,position) + "Foo" + input.substring(position+3 , input.length());
```

or simply you can use replace method.

```
input = input.replace("foo", "Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill, but if you are looking for words in sentences, you could easily use StringTokenizer

```
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
            String output="";
            String temp = "";
            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
               temp = st.nextElement();
        if(temp.equals("foo"))
                       output+=" "+"Foo";
                    else
                       output +=" "+temp;
    }
```